# Multiselect with drag-n-drop in Webix Jet

Tags: drag-and-drop, webix

I'm using Webix Jet to create a simply file manager, but I can't apply `multiselect` with drag-n-drop

For example:

```
{ view: "dataview", id: "fileV", type: "fileView", multiselect: true, drag: true, ... }
```

With easy `select` all works well, so what can be wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What do you think?

```
webix.ui({
  view:"dataview", 
  id:"dataview1",
  select:true,
  multiselect:true,
  type: {
    height: 60
  },
  drag:true,
  template:"<div class='webix_strong'>#title#</div> Year: #year#, rank: #rank#",
  data:[
    { id:1, title:"The Shawshank Redemption", year:1994, votes:678790, rating:9.2, rank:1},
    { id:2, title:"The Godfather", year:1972, votes:511495, rating:9.2, rank:2},
    { id:3, title:"The Godfather: Part II", year:1974, votes:319352, rating:9.0, rank:3},
    { id:4, title:"The Good, the Bad and the Ugly", year:1966, votes:213030, rating:8.9, rank:4},
    { id:5, title:"My Fair Lady",year:"1964",votes:"533,848",rating:"8,9",rank:"5"},
    { id:6, title:"12 Angry Men",year:"1957",votes:"164,558",rating:"8,9",rank:"6"}
  ]
});
```

Snippet: http://webix.com/snippet/a56bce1d

It is what you need?

Comment: Oh yes, thanks! I'm new to it, so apparently I've missed `select:true` before using `multiselect`. Such a silly mistake.